# Why did the installation of the FFmpeg plugin fail?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why did the installation of the FFmpeg plugin fail?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote as I feel this question could be useful, but we could improve this question; let's maybe add a list of steps that you did to install FFmpeg. It seems maybe the automatic download method didn't work. Maybe we should also add a link for the [wolfram community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2189605)

Comment: Note that the specific Wolfram Community post link depends on your OS, I edited question by adding the link for macOS, but deleted when I realized the url is actually OS-specific